# Swift_TransportException: Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect

Tags: php, smtp, xenforo

I am facing issue while sending mail through smtp in Xenforo software. can some configure the issue. I need help.

I have tried many trick but not working. Also the builtin php mail system is not working showing the error that proc_open() function is disabled for security reason.
[THIS IS THE SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDSap.png)

Comment: try specifying "tls://smtp.gmail.com:587" as the server and not tcp://  the 587 port requires a STARTTLS handshake.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)